# Optional parameters in np.eye()

Tags: python, numpy

Got to learn a new function in numpy

```py
np.eye(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=)
```

Looking at the function signature, I thought there might be another way to declare optional parameter as in dtype

So I tried to make my own function foo

```py
   def foo( m , n , d=):
    ...:     print m , n , d
    ...:     
  File "<ipython-input-12-fb227857da46>", line 1
    def foo( m , n , d=):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is clear that this is not possible. Then why numpy guys have written dtype like that and where is the default value for it?

Comment: This function signature i got in spyder text editor's object inspector
Definition : eye(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=)

Type : Function of numpy.lib.twodim_base module

Answer (score 1):

The [function signature of `numpy.eye`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L175) is:

```
def eye(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=float):
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a SyntaxError. It should be

```
def eye(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=float):
```

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py).